# ABAP Display field symbol dynamic in alv

Tags: abap

I am pasting this program for example but i will never know the type of the table (here vbap and vbak).

My goals is to display my field symbol without knowing the types.

Is it possible ?

Here is my code :

```
REPORT  ZTEST_FME_FOL.
type-pools slis .
FIELD-SYMBOLS : <mytable> TYPE ANY TABLE.

DATA :  lv_alv_table  TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
  lv_funct TYPE REF TO cl_salv_functions,
  lv_columns TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table,
  lv_column TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_COLUMN_table.

 SELECT * from vbap INNER JOIN VBAK ON vbap~vbeln = vbak~vbeln UP TO 10 ROWS INTO TABLE <mytable>.


TRY.
 cl_salv_table=>factory(
IMPORTING
  r_salv_table = lv_alv_table
CHANGING
  t_table      = <mytable> ).
CATCH cx_salv_msg .
 ENDTRY.
  lv_funct = lv_alv_table->get_functions( ).
 lv_funct->set_all( Abap_True ).
 lv_columns = lv_alv_table->get_columns( ).
 lv_alv_table->display( ).
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is your point - recreating SE16/SE16N?

Comment: Some kind of :). I would like to have an input text and run whatever query whenever I want. When I want to try a query I have to create a report put my query and test.

Comment: Like this one http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-48002. But this one seems to me very complicated and I hoped find a better way than parsing query manually.

Comment: forgo to notif @vwegert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you 're trying to do there's going to be more validation required than what I've done, but in essence this is what you need. 
Using (dynamic) joins may be particularly tricky.

```
report zevw_test_dynamic_alv.

parameters: p_table type string obligatory.

field-symbols: <gt_table> type standard table.

data: gt_data type ref to data.


start-of-selection.

  create data gt_data type table of (p_table).

  assign gt_data->* to <gt_table>.

  select * from (p_table) up to 10 rows
    into table <gt_table>.

  perform display_results using <gt_table>.  "Your ALV stuff will be in here
```

You may even have to build the fieldcat manually and then use

```
call method cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
  exporting
    it_fieldcatalog = gt_fieldcat[]
  importing
    ep_table        = gt_data.
```

to get the data reference

Comment: I think that it's not possible to do (in the way I was thinking) as you said with your post. Thanks !